# popBackStackImmediate from 4th fragment to the 2nd fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm On the 4th fragment. On 4th fragment view when i click on cancel button it goes on 2nd fragment. but i use popBackStackImmediate it goes on 3rd fragment.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
fmgr.popBackStackImmediate(2, 0);
```

or

```
fmgr.popBackStackImmediate(3, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

should do the trick

---

You can also name your fragment in your transaction

```
fmgr.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container, FRAGMENT, "your_fragment")
    .addToBackStack("your_fragment")
    .commitAllowingStateLoss();

fmgr.executePendingTransactions();
```

And then pop to this fragment:

```
fmgr.popBackStackImmediate("your_fragment", 0);
```

Comment: This fmgr.popBackStackImmediate(3, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); line perfectly worked me. Thank you so much.